# CSS Font Size Inheritance for Header Tags

Tags: css, fonts

I have a page with several H3 header tags and want to increase their font size. When checking the relevant style settings in Firebug the only font size declaration is for the surrounding div element which is set to 16px. However, this 16px font size setting has been overruled but there is no reference anywhere to any other font size declaration. The style settings for the header elements contain no font size declarations. 
Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Comment: Can you share the code? maybe create a jsfiddle?

Comment: it's been done already and it pretty much answered my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser applies font-sizes to header elements and in Firefox (and Chrome and I presume the others) this is set in `em`.  It comes from a 'system' stylesheet.  See this from the Firebug inspector:

[image: Firebug h1 font-size]

Each header has a different font-size set:

- h1 - 2em
- h2 - 1.5em
- h3 - 1.17em
- h4 - 1em
- h5 - 0.83em
- h6 - 0.67em

**Note that to see these styles you have to select 'show user agent' CSS from the 'styles' dropdown:**

[image]

So, you have a parent container at 16px (in fact, that is the browser default font-size anyway), so the `<h3>` at 1.17em would be 1.17 * 16 = 18.72px.

If you explicitly set your `<h3>` to be `1em` in your stylesheet then it would be the same size as the parent.

This fiddle shows each header being affected by a parent container with different font-sizes:

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/VLJXc/)**

Comment: No problem. Could you mark the answer as correct if you're happy with it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your problem completely, maybe it was better if you copy your code here.
but i general your code should be like this for div or H3 elements.

```
<div class="classZ">some text</div>
<h3>some header</h3>

H3 {
     font-size: 18px;
}

div.classZ {
     font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reply. I just wasn't aware that header element font sizes were set by the browser unless you set them in the style sheet.