# Set font-size to header elements inside div

Tags: css, font-size

I had a div with 2 `<h3>` elements inside and by setting the `font-size` property of the parent div I thought that this would have an effect on my header elements and stylize them (but it didn't).
So I create the following simple example and realize that setting font-size to a parent element has actually an effect. (Need help with understanding how CSS and font-size really work...)

[live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xoazvpf2/)

**HTML**:

```
<div>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <h2>Subtitle</h2>
    <p>paragraph text goes here...</p>
</div>
<button>add css rule</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('div').css('font-size','2em');
});
```

Comment: Not clear what is the problem? Yes you can set font-size property from CSS of javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and then maybe you'll understand what's happening :

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    $('div h1, div h2, div p').css('font-size','2em');
});
```

And refer this nice answer (if required :) ):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24153334/3603806

Comment: The `<p>` tag starts at 16px (I guess 1em) and after the button click goes to 32px (2em). If I get it right the header tags get their size depending on the parent div font-size. So the correct way to set font-size is to be specific like `div h3{ ... }`

Answer (score 1):

In the given case, setting font size on the parent element affects the font size of the headings, because the latter is set to `2em`. By definition, in a `font-size` property value, the unit `em` denotes the font size of the parent element.

If you set the font size of heading elements in `pt` or `px` units, for example, it will be unaffected by any change of the parent element font size.